# What’s the last x86 CPU that didn’t place a limit on the size of a single instruction?

Tags: history, instruction-set, cpu, intel, x86

Although useless, [it’s widely known](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972014) the first Intel and derivative CPUs like the Z80 didn’t set a limit on the instruction size. This means that it was possible to fill the whole RAM/ROM with a single instruction through repeating a prefix, and it would still execute!

For example, you could happen an infinity of `0x2E` bytes before a `mov sp,bp` and still get the instruction executed.

If generally the limit today is 15 bytes, I remember the 286 had a 10 bytes limit... But generally what’s the last x86 CPU from that instruction set that didn’t cap instruction size ?

Comment: @RossRidge look at the tags… I’m only paying attention to x86. The z80 can be considered as an extension to the original 8008 that Intel never followed (much like ᴀᴍᴅ’s 3Dnow).

Comment: I'd suggest being more explicit about what is meant by "a single instruction".  If I recall, on the 8086, something like "SS: Rep Movsb" would behave semantically as though the SS prefix was a separate instruction; though would prevent an interrupt from being serviced before executing the next instruction, it would not prevent an interrupt from being serviced *during* a repeated instruction, nor would it get re-executed when the interrupt returned.

Comment: @supercat and compared on a modern ᴀᴍᴅ⁶⁴ ᴄᴘᴜ (even in real mode) where such instruction would be treated as invalid and no part of it would execute.

Comment: @user2284570: I think the 8088/8086 were *intended* to support segment prefixes with repeated string instructions, though they're not safe to use when interrupts are enabled. I suspect the size limits were imposed to avoid the possibility that a user-mode program that attempted to execute a sequence of 65,000 prefix bytes could block interrupts for an excessively long time.

Comment: @supercat The 8086 rep story is a little more complicated: The 8086 does support interrupted prefixed instructions just fine - but only if there is just a single prefix. If there are *multiple* prefixes, like in `SS: REP MOVSW`, only the last one is handled when restarting after an interrupt. This means that `SS: REP MOVSW` transfers the right amount of data (REP is never forgotten), but from a wrong source, whereas `REP SS: MOVSW` performs just a single `SS: MOVSW` after an interrupt. The 80C86 fixed this issue.

Comment: @supercat I thought I read it was because they completely changed the whole architecture of the decoder which was no longer x86 related under the hood and thus no longer able to execute arbitrary sized instructions much like ʀɪꜱᴄ designs.

Comment: @user2284570 The change to RISC under the hood happened with the Pentium Pro, which is more than ten years after the 80286 that alreday had the 10-byte limit.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I've only ever done assembly on 6502 and 680xx, but just because you can have multiple bytes before an instruction and due to some quirk in a bizarre processor family still have the instruction execute, does the instruction really include all those preceding bytes?

Comment: It's not a "bizarre quirk". Several opcode bytes of the x86 instruction space are reserved to be "prefix bytes". These bytes can be put before an instruction to modify the execution of the instruction (like auto-repeating memory transfer instructions, chosing differnt segment registers or holding the bus lock pin during execution). There is no rule on the 8086 (or any later processor) that redundant prefix bytes are forbidden, and even most modern processors will execute instructions with redundent prefix bytes, as long as the total size limit is not exceeded...

Comment: ... As auto-repeated memory transfer instructions are interruptible after each iteration, you can examine the saved instruction pointer from inside the interrupt handler. As long as you don't happen to have the original buggy 8086 core, the instruction point will point to the first prefix byte of the instruction. Thus it is accepted in the 8086 community that all these prefixes are considered part of the instruction, even if they are redundant.

Comment: @GlenYates See my two comments above.

Comment: This only applies to ISAs that have the notion of a "prefix", surely?  Or maybe some hypothetical ISA with infinite indexing: ```LOAD A[R1][R2][R3]…```.  Otherwise, ISAs with variable-length instructions have a natural bound derived from maximal operand length (once you've got the addressing mode, the base register, the index register, and the displacement, there's nothing more to add)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ICL 1900 series didn't permit a SMO (supplementary modifier) instruction to modify a SMO  :-)

Comment: The multiple prefix mis-handling on 8086/8088 is the reason why one sees `REP LOCK MOVSB` inside loops — the inner prefix is preserved, the `REP` is restarted by the loop if it exits prematurely.

Comment: @StephenKitt: [`lock`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lock) doesn't work with [`movsb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq).  A better example would be `rep cs movsb` to override the source from DS to CS.  But yes, doing that inside a loop means that after an interrupt, it executes as a single `cs movsb`, and a loop can sort out the non-zero CX case.  (As opposed to `cs rep movsb`, which after an interrupt could resume as `rep movsb` without the CS segment override, copying from the wrong place, i.e. disaster on those early CPUs with that design bug.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Appendix C (on software compatibility to the 8086), the Intel 286 users manual states the following about instruction length (Page C-2):

> Do not Duplicate Prefixes.
>
> The 80286 sets an instruction length limit of 10 bytes. The only way to violate this limit is by duplicating a prefix two or more times before an instruction. Exception 6 occurs if the instruction length limit is violated. The 8086/8088 has no instruction length limit.

This seems to be wrong, though. The correct exception is exception 13 (0Dh). It is correctly documented in the manual on Page B-9:

> #GP 13 General Protection (Selector or Zero Error Code)
>
> This exception is generated for all protection violations not covered by the other exceptions in this section. Examples of this include:
>
> 1. An attempt to address a memory location by using an offset that exceeds the limit for the segment involved.
> 2. An attempt to jump to a data segment.
> 3. An attempt to load SS with a selector for a  read-only segment.
> 4. An attempt to write to a  read-only segment.
> 5. Exceeding the maximum instruction length of 10 bytes.

The limit has been raised by the 80386 to 15 bytes, because operands and addresses may be 32 bit instead of 16 bit, and you also have extra prefixes. You can find it in the 80386 programmers manual, page 168:

> 9.8.13  Interrupt 13 ── General Protection Exception
>
> All protection violations that do not cause another exception cause ageneral protection exception. This includes (but is not limited to):
>
> 1. Exceeding segment limit when using CS, DS, ES, FS, or GS
>
> [...]
>
> 15. Exceeding the instruction length limit of 15 bytes (this can occur only if redundant prefixes are placed before an instruction)

The limit of 15 bytes is valid until today.

So if we just consider x86 processors, the last processor that did not implement a logic to detect oversized instructions is the 8086 or the 80186. I can not find any reference to a 10-byte limit in the iAPX 86/88/186/188 reference manual, so I am confident to claim that **the last Intel x86 CPU that allowed instructions of unlimited size is the 80186/80188**. The instruction size limit became part of the architecture with the 286 and was changed with the transition from 16 bits to 32 bits.

As all AMD processors up to the (original, non-enhanced) Am486 are licensed copies of the Intel Design, the same applies to AMD processors. For the 16-bit processors, there are other third-party manufacturers like Siemens and Harris, they are also licensed copies of the respective Intel models, so no behavioural difference is to be expected.

There are 80186-compatible processor cores in microcontrollers produced until 2000s at least. They most likely do not include the instruction size limit. The same applies to the V30 and microcontrollers based on it. Basically everything that doesn't have the protected mode (and doesn't have the general protection fault) also doesn't have the instruction size limit.

Comment: And what about clones ? Did ᴀᴍᴅ manufacture 16 bits x86 ?

Comment: So it mights mean other manufacturers built ᴄᴘᴜ without a limited decoder after the 80186 ? What about the Nec V30Mx which is still manufactured today ?

Comment: @MichaelKarcher AMD (and others) licenced up and including the 486.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher the Nec V30Mx supports most 286 and later specific instructions. For protected mode I’d agree to upload something to my Casio.

Comment: @user2284570 "the Nec V30Mx supports most 286 and later specific instructions." - as does the 80186. I checked the V30MX manual and see no hints that the V30MX has an instruction size limit, especially as the V30 manual defines the prefixes as individual instructions.

Comment: The “exception 6” reference in the 286 manual might suggest that at some point, too-long instructions were supposed to result in #UD rather than #GP. Given that #UD was introduced in the 186/188, it would be interesting to test a long instruction there ;-). (The iAPX86/88/186/188 manual isn’t the most accurate manual around; notably, the opcode reference pages weren’t all updated from the 86/88.)

Comment: @MichaelKarcher you see, the difference is the Nec v30mx is an actual ᴄᴘᴜ. You can buy a new Casio using it in almost every store in my country (though that would cost nearly 100€). It can be considered as the last one instead of the original 80186.

Comment: There are a couple of providers of 80186 IP cores nowadays, like HT-Lab (HT80186), iWave or Jamie Iles' open-source S80186. I don't think there will be a "last" implementation of the 80186 architecture in the near future.

Comment: @StephenKitt thinking a bit deeper about why Intel chose #GP instead of #UD, it looks like having the 10-byte limit is acutally a denial-of-service protection, because overly long instructions can increase interrupt latency beyond reasonable value. In protected mode, you have CLI priviledged to protect the operating system from user space code disabling interrupts, so it makes sense to also protect against kilobyte-long non-interruptable instruction decodes. And from that point of view, it makes a lot of sense to make it a "protection fault". And that would explain the appearance on the 286.

Comment: @Michael yes, that does seem like a reasonable explanation. Another argument in favour of something other than #UD is that an instruction with too many prefixes isn’t really #UD anyway...

Answer (score -6):

> Although useless, it’s widely known the first Intel and derivate CPUs like the Z80 didn’t set a limit on the instruction size.

Mind to explain what limit you're asking about? There is no instruction on an 8080 with more than three bytes - and no Z80 instruction with more than 5 (*1).

Furthermore, adding multiple/repeated prefixes don't create a longer instruction - just as adding NOPs in front won't do so.

> If generally the limit today is 15 bytes, I remember the 286 had a 10 bytes limit…

Should this maybe refer to some (prefetch) buffer limits?

Such buffers only organize the way memory access is interleaved with instruction execution. Instructions can (and often do) cover multiple buffers - that's why the 486 had two 16 byte buffers. Access to various parts of the instruction was done by different parts of the pipeline at different times.

Others, like the 68000 or most RISCs didn't have any buffers but read the instruction stream synchronously with its execution.

Caches have blurred that even more.

> But what generally the last CPU from that instruction set which didn’t cap instruction size ?

It seems as if you assume the reverse of the cause and effect. CPU hardware is made to comply to a certain instruction set (for this CPU), thus serving all sizes that are needed, not limiting them.

Further, asking for a 'last' seems to imply a singular line of development, does it? CPUs are defined all the time. There is no singular before and after. Not even within a single company and linage like Intel and their x86 implementations. Strategies for instruction fetch, buffering, decoding and execution have not only changed many times - this includes 'reverting' to something done previously.

---

*1 - In fact, from a CPU's perspective there is no Z80 instruction with more than 3 bytes, as each prefix is handled as a separate instruction, which is clearly shown by pulling the `M1` signal with prefix and opcode byte.

Comment: @Wilson Serious, undocumented opcodes, i.e. bugs, as argument about instruction length?

Comment: @Wilson correct, that’s what I’m meaning. They would still execute.

Comment: @Raffzahn `as each prefix is handled as a separate instruction,` Except any modern ᴀᴍᴅ⁶⁴ ᴄᴘᴜ would reject such thing if the whole length is longer than 15 bytes.

Comment: @Wilson no need for an undocumented instruction. You can for example happen an infinity of `0x66` before a `mov %sp,%bp`.

Comment: @user2284570 Please read in full, as the footnote is about the Z80, which you explicite refer to.

Comment: @Wilson for one, each prefix on a Z80 is handled as a separate instruction, thus addin one is not extending the instruction, but more important putting multiple/repeated prefixes befor an instruction is no different from adding NOPs, which for sure noone will see as a longer instruction, or would you?

Comment: @Raffzahn "Further, adding multiple/repeated prefixes don't create a longer instruction - the same way as adding NOPs in front won't do." - Intel disagrees with you in this regard: The 80286 processor's users says about instruction length: "Do not Duplicate Prefixes: The 80286 sets an instruction length limit of 10 bytes. The only way to violate this limit is by duplicating a prefix two or more times before an instruction. Exception 6 occurs if the instruction length limit is violated." (See document 210498-005, page C-2)

Comment: @MichaelKarcher It still doesn't create a longer instruction. A REP MOVSW with 9 REP is still the same instruction as with one.  The fact that some buffer mechanic kicks in is a complete different issue. When looking at a CPU design it's necessary to distinguish between it's domains. Putting everything into one will at best give a hutspot - but usually rather just a dump :)

Comment: @Raffzahn Do you have any source for the claim that the 10-byte limit on the 80286 is related to a buffer in that processor (e.g. a block diagram or architectural description that referes to this buffer)?

Comment: @MichaelKarcher It's due the way an instruction gets decoded by the IU into the decoded-instruction-queue. At maximum 10 bytes are fetched from the prefetch queue, decoded (and extended for 8 bit constants/offsets and so on) as there is no legal instruction exceeding 10 bytes. It is as well the IU signalling the GPF. Sorry, can't find any reference online more detailed than [this old ACM paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1096458.1096460?download=true)

Comment: @Wilson True, and there are good arguments for either side. Then again, a postponed interrupt allone doesn't make it a single instruction either. Such behaviour can be seen in different context as well. For example (IIRC) a taken branch on a 6502 postpones any interrupt _after_ the next instruction. Still, hard to assume the branch is (when taken) as part of the instruction it branches to, or would you? So far I'm glad Z80 as well as 6502 provide a clear hardware indicator (M1 and Sync) what's to be taken as instruction.

Comment: 1. Actually a sequence of prefixes for Z80 does differ from a sequence of `NOP`s -- unlike the latter, sequence of prefixes *can't be interrupted*.

Comment: 2. There are valid 4-byte instructions in Z80, that do look like prefix, prefix, operand, opcode. This is for example `0xCB 0xDD operand opcode` instructions like `SET 0,(IX+1)`.

Comment: 3. 68000, in fact, has prefetch buffer at least 1 word in size. It often (or always) fetches the opcode of the next instruction before executing memory accesses of the current one.

Comment: Also I suspect that /M1 is a hardware indicator of some decoding done internally on a fetched byte, not *starting* a new instruction. The prefixes may make Z80 jump between different states of internal decoding and executing state machine, but while that process is not finished, we can't say the instruction is over.

Comment: @lvd As said, there are different views here. 1) As shown, being interruptable or not isn't a definite criteria. 2) first, isn't it rather DD CB? At least that's how Zilog says. Second, while the 4th byte can be seen as opcode, it can as well be read as data (bit and reg), and last, this is no difference from an `LD A,x ADD A,y LD y,A` sequence, which as well only works that way. 3) Latching a word ahead isn't the same as a buffer and doesn't change the synchronous nature. 4) True, it's a state machine - like any sequential CPU. Exactly like above LD/ADD sequence is as well. No difference.

Comment: Well, bug (or rather avoidance of actual bugs with interrupts after taken branches) in 6502 is a definite argument that interruptability is not an argument. That's a nice. I could also ask what is meant to be 'asynchronous' or 'synchronous' nature when talking about prefetches. Almost every CPU, at least that with a single clock, is synchronous by definition.

Comment: @lvd The asynchronous part is that the BIU of a 8086 does fetch code whenever there's space within the prefetch buffer and an otherwise unused bus cycle. The 68k on the other hand does only fetch in sync with execution of an instruction (the first word, as you already mentioned, ahead of time) no matter how the instruction mix works out. Instructions with more (potential memory) cycles than words will simply leve memory bandwith unused. As a result the 8086 gains performance not only due shorter encodings but as well due better utilization of memory bandwith (less idle cycles).